# How to insert node at begin ,end and selected position in singly linked list?

Tags: c, malloc, singly-linked-list

I am new for c programming ,i have tried myself inserting node in singly linked list program but i didn't get a proper output and i dont have any idea to correct my program if anybody knows please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head;
int loc;

void addbegin(int num)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=num;
    if(head=NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
}

void addend(int num)
{
    struct node *temp1,*temp2;
    temp1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1->data=num;
    temp2=head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp1;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp2->next != NULL)
        temp2=temp2->next;
        temp1->next=NULL;
        temp2->next=temp1;
    }

}

void pos(int num,int loc)
{
    int length();
    struct node *temp,*cur_ptr,*prev_ptr;

    int i;
    cur_ptr=head;
    if(loc > (length()+1) || loc<= 0)
    {
        printf("it is illegal call:");
    }
    else 
    {
        if(loc == 1)
        {
            addbegin(num);
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=1;i<loc;i++)
            {
                prev_ptr=cur_ptr;
                cur_ptr=cur_ptr->next;
            }
            temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data=num;
            prev_ptr->next=temp;
            temp->next=cur_ptr;
        }
    }
}

int length()
{
    struct node *cur_ptr;
    int count = 0;
    cur_ptr=head;
    while(cur_ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cur_ptr=cur_ptr->next;
        count++;
    }
    return(count);
}
void display()
{
    struct node *temp=NULL;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty:");
    }
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int num;
    head=NULL;
    int choice;
    while(1)
    {
    printf("\nList Operations\n");
    printf("===============\n");
    printf("1.Insert at begin\n");
    printf("2.insert at end\n");
    printf("3.insert at selected position\n");
    printf("4.Display\n");
    printf("5.Exit\n");
    printf("Enter your choice : ");
    if(scanf("%d",&choice)<=0)
    {
        printf("Enter only an Integer\n");

    } 

    printf("enter your choice:");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1: printf("Enter the number to insert at begin : ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            addbegin(num);
            break;
    case 2: printf("Enter the number to insert at end: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            addend(num);
            break;
    case 3: printf("Enter the number to insert at selected position: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            pos(num,loc);
            break;
    case 4: printf("display the values");
            display();
            break;
    case 5: printf("exit");

    display();
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i think the error is in my main function but am not clear in that please help

Comment: `malloc.h` is not standard and moreover, you don't need it here. You already have `stdlib.h`.

Comment: what error are you getting, which line?

Comment: @ajay no errors but my code is wrong , i think i did a mistake in main function but i don't have any idea how to correct it if you know let me know thank you

Comment: @R.A Instead of editing your question to include suggested fixes it would be better if you left it in it's original state as the answers becomes very strange if the comment on issues that have since been edited out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addbegin`method there's at least one obvious error:

```
if(head=NULL)
```

should be

```
if (head == NULL)
```

as you need to compare, not assign.

In your `pos`method you have a function declaration: `int length();` which shouldn't be there, but rather at the top, before main.

Another issue, this time in the display method:

```
void display()
{
    struct node *temp=NULL;
    if(temp==NULL) {
        printf("List is empty:");
    }
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Here temp will always be NULL, I guess you meant to assign `head`to the `temp`pointer, otherwise it will never traverse the list.

And finally, in the `insert at specific position` choice you need to ask for a location value and pass that along too the function call, so add a declaration for `int loc;`in main, and change the third case to this:

```
case 3:
            printf("Enter the number to insert at selected position: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            printf("Enter the position: ");
            scanf("%d",&loc);
            pos(num,loc);
            break;
```

to the

Finally I'm going to quote from the C99 standard, section *5.1.2.2.1 Program startup*:

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

`int main(void) { /* ... */ }`

> or with two parameters (referred to here as
>   argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the
>   function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

So, please, change your declaration of `main`and include a `return`line at the end (possibly `return 0;`indicating successful program exit).

This became rather lengthy. After the suggested changes your program should look something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head;

void addbegin(int num)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=num;
    if(head==NULL) {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
    } else {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
}

void addend(int num)
{
    struct node *temp1, *temp2;
    temp1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1->data = num;
    temp2 = head;
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = temp1;
        head->next = NULL;
    } else {
        while(temp2->next != NULL)
            temp2=temp2->next;
        temp1->next=NULL;
        temp2->next=temp1;
    }
}

int length()
{
    struct node *cur_ptr;
    int count = 0;
    cur_ptr = head;
    while(cur_ptr != NULL) {
        cur_ptr = cur_ptr->next;
        count++;
    }
    return (count);
}

void pos(int num, int loc)
{
    struct node *temp, *cur_ptr, *prev_ptr;

    int i;
    cur_ptr=head;
    if(loc > (length()+1) || loc<= 0) {
        printf("it is illegal call:");
    } else {
        if(loc == 1) {
            addbegin(num);
        } else {
            for(i=1; i<loc; i++) {
                prev_ptr=cur_ptr;
                cur_ptr=cur_ptr->next;
            }
            temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data=num;
            prev_ptr->next=temp;
            temp->next=cur_ptr;
        }
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    if(temp == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty:");
    }

    printf("The list contains the following values:\n");
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        printf("%d\n",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choice, num, loc;
    head = NULL;

    while(1) {
        printf("\nList Operations\n");
        printf("===============\n");
        printf("1.Insert at begin\n");
        printf("2.insert at end\n");
        printf("3.Insert at selected position\n");
        printf("4.Display\n");
        printf("5.Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        if(scanf("%d",&choice)<=0) {
            printf("Enter only an Integer\n");
        }

        switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter the number to insert at begin : ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            addbegin(num);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter the number to insert at end: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            addend(num);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Enter the number to insert at selected position: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            printf("Enter the position: ");
            scanf("%d",&loc);
            pos(num,loc);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Display the values\n");
            display();
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("exit");
            exit(0); // maybe you should exit here.
            display();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Incidentally this is probably a warning in the compiler. Especially when learning and probably writing horrible code, you should crank the warning level up (/W3 in Visual Studio and at least -Wall in gcc/clang)

Comment: Well spotted.  I think that otherwise all the insertion functions look good, if a little verbose.

Comment: please any body edit my full code for working properly

Comment: @R.A I pointed out most of the errors so you should be able to fix them yourself, but in any case I attached a working example, slightly edited.

Comment: @jpw ya now its exiting properly thankyou and display option does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
void addbegin(int num)
{
struct node *temp;
temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->data=num;
  if(head==NULL)
  {
    head=temp;
    head->next=NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
  }
}
```

and

```
void display()
{
struct node *temp=NULL;
temp = head;
  if(temp==NULL)
  {
    printf("list is empty:");
  }
  while(temp!=NULL)
  {
    printf("%d",temp->data);
    temp=temp->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: It will still be broken after this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head;

int loc;

void addbegin(int num)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=num;
    if(head==NULL) //this not assign, you need == to compare
    {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
}

void addend(int num)
{
    struct node *temp1,*temp2;
    temp1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1->data=num;
    temp2=head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp1;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp2->next != NULL)
            temp2=temp2->next;
        temp1->next=NULL;
        temp2->next=temp1;
    }

}

int length()
{
    struct node *cur_ptr;
    int count = 0;
    cur_ptr=head;
    while(cur_ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cur_ptr=cur_ptr->next;
        count++;
    }
    return(count);
}

void pos(int num,int loc)
{
    struct node *temp,*cur_ptr,*prev_ptr;

    int i;
    cur_ptr=head;
    if(loc > (length()+1) || loc<= 0)
    {
        printf("it is illegal call:");
    }
    else 
    {
        if(loc == 1)
        {
            addbegin(num);
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=1;i<loc;i++)
            {
                prev_ptr=cur_ptr;
                cur_ptr=cur_ptr->next;
            }
            temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data=num;
            prev_ptr->next=temp;
            temp->next=cur_ptr;
        }
    }
}


void display()
{
    struct node *temp=head;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty:");
    }
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{

    int num;

    int choice;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nList Operations\n");
        printf("===============\n");
        printf("1.Insert at begin\n");
        printf("2.insert at end\n");
        printf("3.insert at selected position\n");
        printf("4.Display\n");
        printf("5.Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        if(scanf("%d",&choice)<=0)
        {
            printf("Enter only an Integer\n");

        } 

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1: printf("Enter the number to insert at begin : ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            addbegin(num);
            break;
        case 2: printf("Enter the number to insert at end: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            addend(num);
            break;
        case 3: printf("Enter the number to insert at selected position: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            pos(num,loc);
            break;
        case 4: printf("\ndisplay the values: ");
            display();
            break;
        case 5: printf("exit");
            display();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still broken, and also, why include stdafx.h?

Comment: exit(0) is missing in case 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head;

int loc;

void addbegin(int num)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=num;
    if(head==NULL) //this not assign, you need == to compare
    {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
}

void addend(int num)
{
    struct node *temp1,*temp2;
    temp1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1->data=num;
    temp2=head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp1;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp2->next != NULL)
            temp2=temp2->next;
        temp1->next=NULL;
        temp2->next=temp1;
    }

}

int length()
{
    struct node *cur_ptr;
    int count = 0;
    cur_ptr=head;
    while(cur_ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cur_ptr=cur_ptr->next;
        count++;
    }
    return(count);
}

void pos(int num,int loc)
{
    struct node *temp,*cur_ptr,*prev_ptr;

    int i;
    cur_ptr=head;
    if(loc > (length()+1) || loc<= 0)
    {
        printf("it is illegal call:");
    }
    else 
    {
        if(loc == 1)
        {
            addbegin(num);
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=1;i<loc;i++)
            {
                prev_ptr=cur_ptr;
                cur_ptr=cur_ptr->next;
            }
            temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data=num;
            prev_ptr->next=temp;
            temp->next=cur_ptr;
        }
    }
}


void display()
{
    struct node *temp=head;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty:");
    }
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{

    int num;

    int choice;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nList Operations\n");
        printf("===============\n");
        printf("1.Insert at begin\n");
        printf("2.insert at end\n");
        printf("3.insert at selected position\n");
        printf("4.Display\n");
        printf("5.Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        if(scanf("%d",&choice)<=0)
        {
            printf("Enter only an Integer\n");

        } 

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1: printf("Enter the number to insert at begin : ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            addbegin(num);
            break;
        case 2: printf("Enter the number to insert at end: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            addend(num);
            break;
        case 3: printf("Enter the number to insert at selected position: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            printf("Enter the position to insert: 1 for insert at begin, so on: ");
            scanf("%d",&loc);
            pos(num,loc);
            break;
        case 4: printf("\ndisplay the values: ");
            display();
            break;
        case 5: 
            display();
        printf("\n exiting program \n");
        exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct stu{
    int id;
    stu *next = NULL;   
};

stu *first = NULL;
stu *last = NULL;


int opt;

void insert_end();
void display();


int main(){
    
    do{
        
        cout<<"\n\n0.Exit";
        cout<<"\n1.Insert at end in linked list";
        cout<<"\n2.Display linked list";
        
        
        cout<<"\n\nEnter your choice: ";
        cin>>opt;
        
        switch(opt){
            case 1:{
                insert_end_list1();
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                display_list1();
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
    while(opt != 0);
    
    return 0;
}

void insert_end(){
    
    stu *current = new stu;
    
    cout<<"\n\nEnter the student id:";
    cin>>current->id;
    
    if(first == NULL){
        cout<<"\n\nEmpty linked list";
        first = last = current;
    }
    else{
        last->next = current;
        last = current;
    }
    
}

void display(){
    
    stu *p = first;
    
    while(p != NULL){
        cout<<p->id<<" ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    
}
```

This code uses structure for creation of a new node in singly linked list.